# Pythonic way to wait for pressed key for each item in a list - then do something based on key pressed-

Tags: python, key, wait, pressed

I want to iterate through a list of items and log a score for each item. I do not know how to define a function to wait until a key is pressed. I have tried mscvrt and cv. I do not want to use input(), because I want it to work whatever the screen is on. I just want it to know if that key is pressed and then continue. I use python 3.

```
def wait_for_key():
#wait until a key is pressed, return that key
def score_list():
a = [jack, lauren, taylor]
b = []
for item in a:
    score = wait_for_key()
    itemscore = item + ", " + score
    b.append(itemscore)
```

Comment: take a look at pynput ... that works quite well as a crossplatform keylistener

Comment: If by "I want it to work whatever the screen is on" you mean "I want it to detect keypresses even if the window Python is running in doesn't have keyboard focus", and if you're on Windows, then [pygame capture keyboard events when window not in focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380938/pygame-capture-keyboard-events-when-window-not-in-focus) may be of interest to you. (pygame is not required for the solution, despite the title)